# Oracle LEAD & LAG analytics functions

Tags: oracle, lag

I have a temp table using to test and need direction with some analytics function.  Still trying to figure out my real solution.. and any help to lead me in right direction will be appreciated.

```
A1  B1
40  5
50  4
60  3
70  2
90  1
```

Tyring to find the previous value and subtract and add the column

```
SELECT A1, B1,
   (A1-B1) AS C1, 
  (A1-B1) + LEAD((A1-B1),1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS G1
  FROM TEST;
```

The output is not what I expect

```
A1  B1  C1  
40  5   35  
50  4   46  
60  3   57  
70  2   68  
90  1   89
```

From last rows (5th row), first subtract A1 -B2 to get C1..then (C1+ previous A1) - previous row B1  that is ---> `89 + 70 - 2 = 157` (save results in C1 previous row)

4th row: `157+60 -3 = 214`
repeat until the first row...

Expected final output should be ;--

```
A1  B1  C1  
40  5   295 
50  4   260 
60  3   214 
70  2   157 
90  1   89
```

Comment: What do you expect from `order by ROWNUM`? Probably not what will actually happen. Ordering by `ROWNUM` is purely random. (Or, not "purely random", but it is an ordering that has nothing to do with the data in the rows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAG` and `LEAD` only get a single row's value not an aggregation of multiple rows and it is not applied recursively.

You want:

```
SELECT A1,
       B1,
       SUM( A1 - B1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY ROWNUM
                             ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                           ) AS C1
FROM   test;
```

Comment: I would ask the OP about the meaning of `ORDER BY ROWNUM` before copying it as is into a better attempt...